# Unnown token spread operator on Heroku, locally working

Tags: javascript, heroku, babeljs

I'm quite surprised seeing that when I deployed my express app to heroku the error occurs `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...`, indeed I use spread operator and it work when running locally. For some reason I can see the error in heroku logs which crashes my app. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any more info provided by Heroku? Also, what node version is running?

Comment: No more info from heroku, node version is 8.1.1

Comment: Great catch there, then! The issue must be the node version :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spread wasn't supported in node until `8.2.1` try updating your node version

Answer (score 0):

The reason I was asking you about the Node version on my comment, was because spread operator [introduced on node `8.2.1`](https://github.com/uport-project/uport-cli-client/issues/2#issuecomment-371264736), so if Heroku uses version `8.1.1` as you've told me on your comment, then this should cause the error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your node version, node version 8.1.1 not support this operator.